# Get microphone event info

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, microphone

So I'm using a 2in1 IR/2.4Ghz air mouse (Azulle lynk if it helps) to control my PC. It has a microphone button which I have to hold to use the mic but it does not register as a key press(to my knowledge I've tried a couple different programs to see). I'm assuming it unmutes the mic or turns it on or some other process that I don't see. My question is there a way to find out what is happening (mute/process wise) when I press the button and then use autohokey to send a command to my pc. Ultimately Id like to send Windows+Q whenever I press the physical button on my remote.

Comment: Does Windows  has no notification when you enable microphone?

Comment: You can go to volume Mixer to find the state of  your microphone. Update your sound card driver, you might get more information in sound card driver settings.

Comment: So there was the notification when i first added the device of course, but it doesn't show up in my mixer. I can see that it is recognized when i look at my recording device liust, but as far as knowing if its muted/on muted I've got nothing. I'll try updating my driver settings

Comment: So no updates available..